# Codeigniter 4 won't connect to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I spent a days to debug my new codeigniter setup without success, i use mamp as local server. Below are my steps :

- created host from mamp : myci.local
- created db from mamp : myci_db
- composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter myci
- pointing the created host to the myci folder
- from file Config > App.php :
  `public $baseURL = 'https://myci.local/';`

Now adding database parameters to .env :

```
database.default.hostname = localhost
database.default.database = myci_db
database.default.username = root
database.default.password = root
database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi
```

- add migration : `php spark migration:create users`
- execute the migration : `php spark migrate`

Results from the cli :

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type:        CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException
Message:     Unable to connect to the database.
```

I also tried to configure the db from Config/Database.php without success :

```
public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'myci_db',
    'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cacheOn'  => false,
    'cacheDir' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 3306,
];
```

I don't understand why this doesn't works, CI4 is not production ready yet? thank you.

NB : those db parameters works on other sites with the same mamp server.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have used the --all in the command, it triggers something else.

wrong:

```
php spark migrate --all
```

correct:

```
php spark migrate
```

Execute correct command.